# Export the list of file name from CSV file and copy to another directory with python

Tags: python, csv

i have one csv file that include the list of file:
nome
Desert
Hydrangeas
Jellyfish
Koala
Lighthouse
Penguins
Tulips
I would like to create one script with python for copy this list of file from one directory to another directory, i can do this :

```
import csv
import os
import shutil
source = os.listdir("C:\Test")
destination = "C:\Test1"
with open('semplice1.csv') as csvfile:
       reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
       for row in reader:
           print(row['nome'])
```

in this wway i can print the name of the file.
Can you help me to complete the code for copy only the list file?
Thanks.`enter code here`

Comment: Have you tried [`shutil.copy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) or `shutil.copytree()`?

Comment: I can't resolve :-(

Comment: Can you include a few lines from the CSV file you are parsing so that we know what the format is?

Comment: Is the goal to copy files from "C:\Test" to some other directory? Or to copy files from multiple sub-directories, e.g. "C:\Test\XXX" to another location?

Comment: Yes i can parsing the list name fro mmy CSV ven i use the following code:
import csv
import os
import shutil
source = os.listdir("C:\Test")
destination = "C:\Test1"
with open('semplice1.csv') as csvfile:
       reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
       for row in reader:
           print(row['nome'])
           a = str(row['nome'])
          # shutil.copyfile(source + row['nome'],destination)

Comment: I see:
Desert
Hydrangeas
Jellyfish
Koala
Lighthouse
Penguins
Tulips
>>>

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `os.listdir()` returns a *list* of files contained in the directory that you give it - in this case "C:\test".

Later on, when you then try and concatenate `source` with the individual files, you are therefor attempting to combine a list with a str. This is why you are getting the `TypeError`.

If all of the files are contained directly in "C:\test", then you can drop the `os.listdir()` and do:

```
import csv
import os
import shutil

source = "C:\Test"
destination = "C:\Test1"

with open('semplice1.csv') as csvfile:
       reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
       for row in reader:
           print(row['nome'])
           a = row['nome']
           shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(source, a), destination)
```

Note the use of `os.path.join()` also as a better solution for building filepaths up.

Comment: [answer] I try to run the script that correct me but i have the error :
    shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(source, ['nome']), destination)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 85, in join
    result_path = result_path + p_path
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
>>>

Comment: Sorry, there was a small typo in the script - should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem with this code:

```
import csv
import os
import shutil

source = "C:\Test"
destination = "C:\Test1"

with open('semplice1.csv') as csvfile:
       reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
       for row in reader:
           print(row['nome'])
           shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(source, row['nome']), os.path.join(destination, row['nome']))
```